# Why do I keep getting Error 500 on this simple Python-CGI when using subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, apache, cgi, subprocess

I try to trigger system call via a Python 2.7 CGI using this simple script:

```
import subprocess

print 'Content-Type:text/html'
print
print '<!DOCTYPE html>'
print '<html>'
print '<body>'
print '<pre>'

try:
    subprocess.check_call('/bin/ls')
except:
    pass

print '</pre>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

The script runs fine in the shell (even when using the Apache user to run it), but I **always** receive an Error 500 when running the CGI via the web server. I tried setting *shell=True* but this does not make a difference. The only message I receive in the Apache error log is:

```
malformed header from script.
```

Yet, if I uncomment the subprocess call inside the  tags, Apache no longer complaints about the headers and I receive the expected result (Status 200, but of course without the system call).

Am I missing something? Do I have configure Apache to allow for system calls from the CGI? Does such configuration have to be made locally (.htaccess) or globally (/etc/apache2/...)? Any advice on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To confuse me even further, using the deprecated os.popen() idiom instead does actually work. Just don't ask me why ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It apparently happens because the subprocess produces output, which is *not* piped throug the caller's stdout, as it should, but is flushed *directly* to the output. Thus, in effect, the output of `ls` ends up as the CGI-header, hence the 500 error.

`os.popen` worked, because it does the expected stdout piping for you.

But you can also do the same this (preferred) way:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('/bin/ls')
```

(Note: the subprocess is now running asynchronously, unlike with your original `subprocess.check_call`. If you need a synchronous call (e.g. you need the output of the child...), you could do something like

```
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

etc. to approximate the original synchronous control flow. And don't forget to add `stdout=PIPE` to the `Popen()` call then.)

Comment: A related thorough post: http://www.znasibov.info/blog/html/2010/04/24/inside_python_subprocess_communication.html